# Visual Studio 2013 c++ Folder management

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I switched to VS2013 for my C++ projects.

I really wonder why the folder management is so bad?! 
Virtual folders only, urgh.

Creating a new sub folder in "Source Files" called "Core". Adding a new class (right click on "core") => The class gets created in "Source Files" and not in "core". Also the header file is placed inside "Header Files".

**Why even create virtual sub folder, when VS will not place the files inside these folders?!**

Another drawback for me is, that the files are all located in my project root. 
`#include "subfolder/myClass.h"` leads to an error this way ...

I also deleted the "Source/Header Files" folders and created my own "src" folder. Same problem.

Switching to the Explorer view and creating real folders (and adding the files to the solution) also messes this up.

**Is there some kind of plugin to fix this weird behavior?! Or any other way to work around this?!**

C# folder management works like a charm to me ... there I don't have to create a class and put the files in the correct folder afterwards...and no virtual folders...

Comment: When you create a source file you can specify (including create) a directory. You can also include existing files in a subdirectory.

Comment: Hi, yeah for source files it seems to work. But not for new classes (using the wizard)

Comment: History plays a big role, the C++ build model dates from the 1970s.  There are a lot of intermediate build steps and a lot of files that don't necessarily have anything to do with compiling code.  You get a logical *view* of the project, not correlated to the folder structure.  Kinda obvious, there is no directory named "Header Files".  And while its content is typically useful to you, those files play no role whatsoever in building the project, they never get passed to a build tool.  You'll get used to it.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your answer. The virtual folders are okay, I can deal with it, but at least structuring my classes inside these virtual folders without dragging them manually would be nice. The "Header Files" folder seems to be rather useless to me, especially if I want to have a decent organization I have to create virtual sub folders twice (one for cpp and one for hpp ...). So I guess I have to live with this kinda buggy behavior

Comment: Interesting. I've never used the wizard for creating classes so never noticed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is a way to use real folders instead of virtual ones.
You have to click on your project in the solution explorer and then on "show all files" in the title bar of the solution explorer.

[image]

After you have done that you can move your files into "real" folders in your file system.

Comment: I've been using VS for 4 years now and didn't know that. Wow.

Comment: Hi, yes I know. Switching to the "explorer view/show all files" shows the same behavior with the "new class wizard". Adding a new folder and creating a new class ,will put the files in the root path of your project, not inside the folder. I guess I have to stick to manually sorting everything. And just use ONE view. Filter or Explorer...meh. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: if you move the files inside the solution explorer they will also be moved in your file system (if you are in "show all files" mode)